# Cannot insert values if not exists using "NOT IN" in SQL-Server table

Tags: sql-server

By executing following queries, I cannot insert value if not exists using "NOT IN" in SQL-Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Name VARCHAR(20))
GO

INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES ('bk'), ('ck'), ('kk')
GO

CREATE TABLE #tt (Name VARCHAR(50))
GO

INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES ('jk'), ('dk'), ('kk')
GO
```

```
--Script 1
INSERT INTO tbl (Name)
    SELECT  Name
    FROM    #tt t
    WHERE   t.name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM tbl)
```

```
-- Script 2
INSERT INTO tbl (Name)
    SELECT  DISTINCT t.name
    FROM    #tt t
    LEFT    JOIN tbl t1 ON t.name=t1.name
    WHERE   t1.name IS NULL
```

Comment: Script 1 inserts zero records but Script 2 inserts 2 records as intended, why "not in" doesn't help here ?

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please write your question properly with actual result and current result.

Comment: also dont use not in,when you have null .you will get unexpected results.Use not exists

Comment: Is there a question there? I couldn't find it...

Comment: @Mr.BK I execute above and in script1 it try to insert 2 record ('jk' and 'dk') and script 2 does not insert anything because its filter the data with above script. **not in** work because if I remove from script 1, answer will be 'kk'.

Comment: Script 1 works fine for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated your question (tbl8 to tbl in second query), after this I again run and yes, first query insert data and second not, because in your second select query does not return any result. So what is the issue dear?

Answer (score 0):

Always use NOT EXISTS (equivalent for LEFT JOIN/IS NULL) instead of NOT IN. The way NOT IN behaves is different in this scenario.

Refer to https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/.